# Oracle SQL : how to find just record from a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where there is a PrimaryKey, Foreign Key.
I just want to find the list of one Primary per Foreign Key.
Example
[image: MYTABLE]

I need a query that returns only Primary Keys (1 or 2 or 3) and (4 or 5) or (6 or 7 or 8)
Essentially 1,4 and 6. How can I get just one PK for each Foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select foreignKey, min(primaryKey)
from t
group by foreignKey;
```

If you want a random value, you can use the `keep` syntax:

```
select foreignKey,
       min(primaryKey) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.random)
from t
group by foreignKey;
```

And if you had many columns, you could use `row_number()` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.primarykey = (select min(t2.primarykey) from t t2 where t2.foreignkey = t.foreignkey);
```

Comment: I have a subsequent question. I have another table which has the list of all the above Primary keys exists. Lets say Table B. How can I check - which of the min(primary key ) coming out of the above query - does not exist in Table B?

Comment: @Marco . . . Just use `not exists` in the `where` clause.  If that is not clear, then ask a *new* question with an appropriate explanation.

Comment: Seems like I cannot post another question for 90 mins. I do understand NOT EXISTS and WHERE but the Group by is throwing me off.