# Oracle SQL Subquery - Usage of NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, not-exists

I used a query to find a list of Primary Keys.  One Primary key per each ForiegnKey in a table by using below query.

```
select foreignKey, min(primaryKey)
from t
group by foreignKey;
```

Let us say this is the result : 1,4,5

NOw I have another table - Table B that has list of all Primary keys. It has 1,2,3,6,7,8,9

I want a write a query using the above query So that I get a subset of the original query(above) that does not exist in Table B. I want 4 and 5 back with the new query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
select foreignKey, min(primaryKey)
from t
group by foreignKey
having min(primarykey) not in (select pk from b);
```

You should also be able to express this as `not exists`:

```
having not exists (select 1
                   from b
                   where b.pk = min(t.primaryKey)
                  )
```

Comment: If the Table B has a couple of million records and first part of the query barely returns 10 records- Does the approach change. Is there a better option? Just curious

Comment: @Marco . . . It seems strange to me that you are only comparing the minimum id to `b`, but that is what you are asking for.  But `not exists` should be fine assuming you have an index on the column in `b`.

Comment: Some data corruption happened. We are trying to figure out the missing data. It does not have to be min. But random would have worked too. like how you had suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904626/oracle-sql-how-to-find-just-record-from-a-group). I just need the foreign key to be identified- Where primary Key is missing when compared to Table B.